# Handling errors in PDO when MySQL query fails

Tags: php, pdo, error-handling

I've recently changed all my `mysql.*` to `PDO`. I've been having a few issues and trying to get used to it.

My question is how to properly call an error when there is an issue in the sql statement. Normally I wouldn't use `try, catch` but is there another alternative?
Suppose I have the following:

```
private function init()
{
    $query = $this->_PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM here WHR name='john'");
    if($query->execute())
    {
        $this->_sql_rows = $query->rowCount();
    }
    else
    {
        print_r($query->errorInfo());
    }

}
```

This checks whether the `execute` method worked and if not, output errors. In this case it should as there is a spelling mistake. Normally when I do this, I never see any errors come out and must always use the method above to output an error. Is this a reliable and appropriate way of handling such errors?

Comment: I prefer exceptions myself (and you should never have those typos in production, only on development). But: you can call a [`setAttribute()`](http://www.php.net/pdo.setattribute) on the the PDO object to alter how it handles errors.

Comment: You've read through http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski hmm, that's a good place to start. Thanks!

Comment: Check this too, it's a very good tutorial for PDO: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, it is not.

Just like almost every PHP user, you have quite vague and uncertain idea on error handling. And the code mostly looks like a dummy code from sandbox example. Speaking of your current approach, frankly - it's just terrible. On a live site it will only scare an innocent user, while webmaster would have no idea what's going on.

So, first of all you have to make your mind *what is error handling you are looking for.*

There are different possible scenarios, but most convenient is just to follow the way PHP handles all other errors. To do that just set PDO in exception mode. This way you'll be always notified of all the errors occurred. So - just add this line right after connect.

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

and thus your function become short and clean

```
private function checkUser($user)
{
    $stmt = $this->_PDO->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE name=?");
    $stmt->execute(array($user));
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```

Comment: Yea, like the other user mentioned also about the setAttribute. I've looked into and it's a lot simpler than if and else statements and other useless stuff. Please do pardon my PHP, I don't usually deal with PHP a lot.